# how to install mysqli on windows iis server?

Tags: mysql, installation

I am trying to run mysqli on my remote windows server and I keep getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

I assume mysqli is not installed on my remote server. So how do I install mysqli on my remote server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mysqli` is a PHP extension. So all you have to do is enable that extension in your `php.ini` file.

Uncomment:

```
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

To:

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

If using a share hosting account, you may have to create a `.htaccess` and point it to your own copy of `php.ini`.

To do that, you could try the following:

- If php is installed as a module: In your `.htaccess` put `SetEnv PHPRC /location/todir/containing/phpinifile`
- If php is installed as a cgi extension, put your `php.ini` in the `cgi-bin` folder.
- For some hosts, you can also just put your `php.ini` in the folder where you would usually put your `.htaccess` files.

Comment: can give example how to redirect to my php.ini file

Comment: I was wondering should i update all values of php.ini ,Like there are so many setting in php.ini, while i need only setting for mysqli, So do i include other setting also???..also my server is windows platform.so i think .htaccess will not work, can you provide code for web.config

Comment: Are you running IIS? If you are running apache on windows, `.htaccess` should still work. If you have redirected `php.ini` to your own copy, then you need to provide a full and complete `php.ini`.

Comment: yes my server is running IIS, So how use this for IIS server??

Comment: I don't have any experience with IIS, but here's a link showing how you can use a custom `php.ini` for each website: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/745/enable-per-site-php-configuration-on-iis-60-and-iis-7-and-above/

Answer (score 5):

I am using Windows-10 / IIS server / PHP Version 7.3.10
Resolved using below changes.

inside the php.ini file
non-working configuration

```
;extension=mysqli
```

```
extension_dir = ext
```

working configuration:

```
extension=C:\<my-work-folder-path>\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll
```

```
extension_dir = "C:\<my-work-folder-path>\php\ext"
```

After saving changes to file

```
IISRESET
```

Comment: It worked for me, just created __php.ini__ file copying existing file __php.ini-production__ and changed these two lines. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, the full path solved my problem. Before: extension=ext  After extension=C:\...

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:

- Copy and paste **php.ini-production** file, changing its name for **php.ini** (root directory of PHP)
- Change following lines

**;   extension=mysqli**
**;   extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so**

to anything like this:

**extension="C:\Program Files\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll"**
**extension_dir="C:\Program Files\php\ext"**

Special thanks to Baburaj's answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Working on windows)

I was facing exactly the same issue.

In my case, the problem was that I had saved the php.ini file as a text file. As soon as I converted the text file to *"All Files"* in notepad and gave it the *".ini"* extension, it became a *"Configuration Settings File"* and it worked.

You may check if this is the case by going through the loaded configuration file row in `phpinfo()`. If the value is 'none', you may be facing a similar issue.

**Note**: I had already uncommented the extensions and fixed the extension directory.